react-native-vision-camera unable to map the values in the frame to screen width and height
I am using native-vision-camera (v4.1.0) in my project to scan barcodes. However the coordinates I am getting in IOS is ambiguous and I am unable to map those values to actual coordinates in the screen. This is the code I have
const device = useCameraDevice("back");
const [layout, setLayout] = useState<
  LayoutChangeEvent["nativeEvent"]["layout"]
>({ x: 0, y: 0, width: 0, height: 0 });
const [codeScannerHighlights, setCodeScannerHighlights] = useState<[]>([]);
const [scanFrame, setScanFrame] = useState<CodeScannerFrame>({
  height: 1,
  width: 1,
});

const codeScanner: CodeScanner = {
  codeTypes: ["ean-13"],
  onCodeScanned: (codes, frame) => {
    setScanFrame(frame);
    setCodeScannerHighlights(
      codes.map((code) => ({
        height: code.frame?.width ?? 0,
        width: code.frame?.height ?? 0,
        x: code.frame?.y ?? 0,
        y: code.frame?.x ?? 0,
      }))
    );
  },
};

const onLayout = (evt: LayoutChangeEvent) => {
  if (evt.nativeEvent.layout) {
    setLayout(evt.nativeEvent.layout);
  }
};

const HightlightBox = ({ highlight, layout, scanFrame }): JSX.Element => {
  return (
    <View
      style={[
        {
          position: "absolute",
          borderWidth: 2,
          borderColor: "red",
        },
        {
          right: highlight.x * (layout.width / scanFrame.height),
          top: highlight.y * (layout.height / scanFrame.width),
          height: highlight.height * (layout.width / scanFrame.height),
          width: highlight.width * (layout.height / scanFrame.width),
        },
      ]}
    />
  );
};

return (
  <View>
    <Camera
      style={StyleSheet.absoluteFill}
      device={device}
      isActive={true}
      codeScanner={codeScanner}
      onLayout={onLayout}
    ></Camera>
    {/* <Mask /> */}
    {codeScannerHighlights.map((hightlight, key) => (
      <HightlightBox
        key={key}
        highlight={hightlight}
        layout={layout}
        scanFrame={scanFrame}
      />
    ))}
  </View>
);

I was referring to https://medium.com/@susumtang/improve-user-experience-with-barcode-highlight-box-using-react-native-vision-camera-code-scanner-ff7f67089aab to setup the base for this and after a couple of tweaks I was able to get this working on android. However for IOS the coordinates, specially the width of the frame seems to be not correct.
For example this is the output I get from the log,
[{"frame":{"y":91.03336715698242,"width":3.0000076293945312,"height":118.10350799560547,"x":105.4999885559082},"type":"ean-13","corners":[{"y":209.1368776739407,"x":105.49999203584794},{"x":108.49999966524247,"y":209.13687756664882},{"y":91.03336957104347,"x":108.49999335555874},{"y":91.03336967833533,"x":105.49998572616421}],"value":"2103456001794"}]

I would be open to any alternative ways to limit the scan area. I also tried the downgraded versions of this library as well.

Have you found a solution to this? I'm having the same problems. The point values I get from the library is not relevant to the real coordinates in the screen. Even after using PixelRatio proportion, it still does not match.

@FarukYazici unfortunately no :(
